# How to use ng2-file-upload to post a request without the file?

Tags: angular, ng2-file-upload

I come across a question about ng2-file-upload, If I use it to upload at least a file, it works well. But if I do not select any file, it will crash and reload, and I can't get any error. Anyone know how to use ng2-file-upload to post a request without the file? 
This is my code:

```html
<div>
  <span>Upload：</span>
  <input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" (change)="selectedFileOnChanged($event)"/>
</div>
```

```js
uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({    
    url: "http://www.download.com:80/uploadFile",   
    method: "POST",    
    itemAlias: "uploadedfile"
});
this.uploader.uploadAll();
```

Comment: null check for `uploader` before submitting the form

Comment: what is the case here, since it shouldn't upload if you do not choose a file?

Comment: I want to use ng2-file-loader to post a request. Sometimes the request has files, but sometimes it has not. Do you kown how to do this?

Comment: Still doesn't really answer my question, it shouldn't try uploading if you do not choose a file?

Comment: @ZhangXu were you able to send a request without a file?